# Algorithm for assembly arithmetic

Tags: assembly, x86

Can someone check if my algorithm is correct

```
.data
    val1        BYTE        15h
    val2        WORD        8765h
    val3        DWORD   0FFFFh
    val4        WORD        7FFFh
```

Implement the following expression in assembly language: `val3 = (-val4 + val3) – val2`

```
movzx eax, val4
neg eax
add val3, eax
movzx ebx, val2
sub val3 ebx
```

Comment: did i use movzx correctly, because the types are different, and I wanted to changed to 32 buts

Answer (score 2):

The code looks correct if your 16-bit variables are assumed to hold non-negative values only.

However, the comma is missing in the last instruction.